# Vue multiple color-pickers on one page

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, color-picker

I have this snippet:

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-row justify="center" align="center">
            <v-col v-for="col in colors" :key="col" class="shrink" style="min-width: 220px;">
                <v-text-field v-model="col" hide-details class="ma-0 pa-0" solo>
                    <template v-slot:append>
                        <v-menu v-model="menu" top nudge-bottom="105" nudge-left="16" :close-on-content-click="false">
                            <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
                                <div :style="swatchStyle" v-on="on" />
                            </template>
                            <v-card>
                                <v-card-text class="pa-0">
                                    <v-color-picker v-model="col" flat />
                                </v-card-text>
                            </v-card>
                        </v-menu>
                    </template>
                </v-text-field>
            </v-col>
        </v-row>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
    data: () => ({
        color: '#1976D2',
        colors: [
            "#1aaa31",
            "#1ccc31",
        ],
        menu: false,
    }),
  computed: {
    swatchStyle() {
      const { color, menu } = this
      return {
        backgroundColor: color,
        cursor: 'pointer',
        height: '30px',
        width: '30px',
        borderRadius: menu ? '50%' : '4px',
        transition: 'border-radius 200ms ease-in-out'
      }
    }
  }
})
```

[Here is a pen](https://codepen.io/JamieCurnow/pen/KKPjraK)

Each of them (color-pickers) closing right after selecting, I want to prevent this, it's working fine with a single component.

I've already set `:close-on-content-click` to `false`, but don't really understand why they opening at once and closing right after click without `v-for` it works fine.

Comment: You use same `v-model="menu"` for all items